# order of operators in F# query expression

Tags: f#, query-expressions

Does the order of query expression operators matter? Idk, but sometimes (in some selections) it does, but sometimes it doesn't (or maybe it does but implicitly handles some particular occasions).

Is is mandatory that **select** operator must go last? in pretty much every combination it complains if you don't write it as a last statement, but in case of **take n**, this operator can go after **select**

I'm just interested in how the process of execution acts?

This brings me to another question. If it iterates over Iterable collection, and thus on the first iteration it selects some one(first) value, how **order** works on that one(first) value? it would be clear if first it returned sequence, and then executed order on that sequence.. but seems like it executes **sortBy** at every iteration (?). I'm interested in what the design of the executed algorithm is.

Here is my example of Query Expression.

```
let sq = query {
   for p in datasource do
   where p.age>20
   sortBy p.age
   select p
}
```

Explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this question is correctly tagged? I don't recognize any of that as standard F#. Also, concrete example code does, in general, help a lot.

Comment: Not so much explanations but maybe https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp and possibly more specific: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fs and https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fsi  And if new to CE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions. I assume you have read the fine print at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer, this all looks standard to me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens: The first version of the question did not contain any actual code - and inferring code from natural language is a little ambiguous generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need to guess, we can find out.

```
let sample = Seq.init 10 (fun i -> i * 10) |> Seq.map (fun i -> { age =  i }) 
let sq = query {
   for p in sample do
   where (p.age > 20)       
   sortBy p.age
   select p
}

sq |> Seq.toList |> ignore
```

The generated IL (cleaned up) looks like

```
IL_004e: newobj instance void Program/sq@16::.ctor(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryBuilder)
IL_0053: callvirt instance [...] For<class Program/Person,      
IL_005d: callvirt instance [...] Where<class Program/Person,    
IL_0067: callvirt instance [...] SortBy<class Program/Person,   
IL_0071: callvirt instance [...] Select<class Program/Person,
```

Suppose we change the order of sortBy

```
let sq = query {
   for p in sample do
   sortBy p.age
   where (p.age > 20)       
   select p
}
```

The new IL will be:

```
IL_006c: callvirt instance [...] For<class Program/Person,      
IL_0076: callvirt instance [...] SortBy<class Program/Person,   
IL_0080: callvirt instance [...] Where<class Program/Person,    
IL_008a: callvirt instance [...] Select<class Program/Person,
```

You can clearly see that it follows the exact order you define the query in.
This wouldn't matter for T-SQL comprehensions because the query will be translated by an Expression visitor, but for object queries, query expressions are pretty much just syntactic sugar for you.

Answer (score 1):

Method #2:

You can extend the query expression module to include an operator for side-effects. This is simply a port of Interactive Extensions' `DoAction` method.

```
module QueryExtensions =

    type QueryBuilderEx() =
        inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()

        [<CustomOperation("doAction", MaintainsVariableSpace = true)>]
        member __.Do(source : Linq.QuerySource<'T,System.Collections.IEnumerable>, action) =            
            new Linq.QuerySource<'T,System.Collections.IEnumerable>(source.Source |> Seq.map (fun v -> action(v); v))


let query = QueryExtensions.QueryBuilderEx()
```

Now you can debug the order like so

```
let sq = query {
       for p in sample do
       sortBy p.age       
       where (p.age > 20)       
       doAction (printfn "Next -> %A")
       select p
    }
```

If you move it above the `where`, you'll see that it reflects those records before filtering.

Comment: To elaborate, @Astri is extending the `query` [computational expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions). Thank you @astri for this nice little trick.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens you're very much welcome! There're a lot of nice operators in `System.Interactive` that I wish would come over to FSharp `Seq`.